# importing CSV file into sqlite table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, csv

I've imported a CSV file into an sqlite table. everything went fine except it included quotes " " around the data in the fields. not sure why because there are no quotes in the CSV file.

anyone know how to avoid this or get rid of the quotes somehow?

Here's a screenshot from the firefox sqlite import settings I'm using:

[image]

thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to select "Double quotes ("), if necessary (Standard)" under "Fields enclosed by"?

Comment: that worked. I had tried that before but I needed to empty the table before it overwrote the existing data. worked great. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that there really ARE double-quotes around the data.  If you use Windows, a CSV will automatically open in Excel and it looks like there are no quotes because Excel interprets the file properly.  However, I bet if you open the file in Notepad there will be quotes around the strings.

and then, as pointed out in your discussion above, truncate your sqlite table and reimport the data, indicating that the fields are enclosed by double quotes.